# how to add smooth animation in fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

i searched a lot for adding smooth sticky header for this particular code..nothing works for me

anyone, please add animation for this coding..

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $("#header").affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        , bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('#copy').outerHeight(true))
        }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "please add animation for this coding" what animation? any? $('#header').fadeOut(600);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css

```
#header{
  transition-duration : 2s;
}
```

hope it help